# Why does Kylo Ren's lightsaber sound like a lawnmower?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, kylo-ren

It started on a Tuesday morning; I was using my Mower and then it hit me. 
Why did Kylo Ren get his lightsaber at **Lowes**?  or the **Home Depot**?

Comment: Isn't it because it's kinda shabby? A home-made lightsaber made by someone not fully trained/ready to build one?

Comment: To reopen voter... I suspect that if the reopen is successful it will be closed again as a duplicate. There are many questions that cover the design of Kylo's lightsaber...

Answer (score 3):

Kylo Ren's lightsaber sounds so raw and animalistic because it was supposed to mirror his own raw and unrestrained abilities.

David Acord a sound designer for *The Force Awakens* explained this in [an interview with Nerdist](http://nerdist.com/kylo-rens-signature-force-sound-was-a-purring-kitty-say-sound-designers/):

> David Acord: I think the most obvious new sound effect in the movie is Kylo’s lightsaber. **We were attempting, along with his Force power effect, to create sound effects that would mimic his persona, which is this raw power he has that’s not quite formed. He’s not well trained, but he’s extremely powerful. It’s a little wild and dangerous.** The sword itself, the look of the sword has the extra darts coming out the side, and it’s really sparky and wavery and it looks a little homemade. **The idea of the sound was to match that–something that sounds like raw energy, just pure power, very brutal and kind of wild and dangerous sounding.**

Comment: Yeah...but what kind of animal is a lawnmower?